# Oracle 10g backup issue

Tags: backup, oracle

Introduction:
*I have to set up a backup concept for an old Oracle 10g installation. The server is old and poorly managed, but I have to ensure we have rock solid backups until the system will be taken offline in early 2014.
I've already read a few lines about exp and RMAN in the oracle documentation. Sadly the system lacks any oracle tools (no sqlplus => no command line, no exp & co) and I'd prefer not to install additional software right now.*

Is there an easy way to set up a backup solution (exp / rman) from the client machine?

PS: While we don't have commandline on the system itself - we got the Oracle Managment console installed on a client. So client based backup solutions would be fine

Answer (score 2):

The backup tools provided by Oracle can be used from the client side, but to do so, you need SYSDBA privileges. You can use the `rman`, `expdp` or `exp` commands from the client side. Using `rman` is recommended, since it is the only one which is capable of taking differential backups. To use `rman`, connect to the server using the

```
connect target sys@SERVERNAME
```

command, where "SERVERNAME" is the TNS entry for the server.

`rman` and `expdp` will make backups on the server, so for example if you allocate a disk channel in `rman`, it will try to write backup on the server, and if you allocate a tape device, the server must have access to the device.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

####### env #######
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export TNS_ADMIN=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/asm/network/admin
export ORACLE_SID=WIND1
export NLS_LANG=american
export NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD, HH24:MI:SS'

export BACKUP_LOC=/rman_backups/WIND1

####### log ######
export DATE=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
LOGFILE=$BACKUP_LOC"/log/rman_backup-"$DATE".log"

exec > $LOGFILE 2>&1

echo "Start of Prod CDA Full Backup " $DATE

####### rman backup database, archive, controlfile and spfile #######
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/rman << EOF

connect target sys/password1

CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 3 BACKUP TYPE TO COMPRESSED BACKUPSET;
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 14 DAYS;

run {
sql 'alter system checkpoint' ;

BACKUP DEVICE TYPE DISK database FORMAT '/rman_backups/WIND1/database/%T_datafile_s%s';

sql 'alter system archive log current' ;

BACKUP DEVICE TYPE DISK archivelog all FORMAT '/rman_backups/WIND1/database/%T_archive_s%s' filesperset 20;

BACKUP DEVICE TYPE DISK CURRENT CONTROLFILE FORMAT '/rman_backups/WIND1/database/%T_control_s%s';

BACKUP DEVICE TYPE DISK SPFILE FORMAT '/rman_backups/WIND1/database/%T_spfile_s%s';
}

CROSSCHECK BACKUP;
CROSSCHECK ARCHIVELOG ALL;

DELETE NOPROMPT EXPIRED ARCHIVELOG ALL;
DELETE NOPROMPT OBSOLETE;

exit
EOF
```